# Node-Thermal-Printer Not Connecting to Epson T88IV Printer

Tags: node.js, thermal-printer, epson, econnrefused

## I am trying to print to an Epson TM-T88IV printer from javascript.

(This is a thermal receipt printer.)

#### Status:

- The printer is connected to the network via ethernet.
- I can successfully ping the printer.
- I can access the printer web configuration page.
- I have reset the printer.
- I can print to the printer using an Epson's Mac OS print driver.

#### Development Environment:

- I am running Mac OS X 10.10
- I reinstalled Node and NPM using Homebrew.
- Ran: brew update...brew doctor...brew symlink...

#### Issue:

I cannot figure out how to resolve the ECONNREFUSED error that I am encountering.

#### Already Tried:

- Ran it on Tonicdev.com to no avail for clues. [Link](https://tonicdev.com/kevinkurpe/57925d6b9c859212009744b3) to Tonic Notebook.
- I have searched and read every **ECONNREFUSED** question on Stackoverflow.
- I have tried placing this code in a standalone **print.js** file and calling:

  `node print.js`

#### Error:

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.77.22:8008
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1035:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '192.168.77.22',
  port: 8008 }
```

#### Update

I checked which ports were open/available on the device. It turns out that Epson's SDK documentation was incorrect! The actual port that is open for TCP/Printer requests is 515, not 8008. Good grief!

```
nc -z 192.168.77.22 1-6000
```

The **printer.init** isn't establishing a connection. The **printer.isPrinterConnected** is returning **false**.

I re-tried Epson's epos SDK with the **correct port**. I got the following error: `ERROR_TIMEOUT`.

**So, I think I might not be setting a TimeOut value correctly?**

#### Node-Thermal-Printer (Code)

```js
var printer = require("node-thermal-printer");
printer.init({
    type: 'epson',
    interface: '/dev/usb/lp0',
    ip: "192.168.77.22",
    port: '515'
});

printer.isPrinterConnected(function(isConnected){
    console.log(isConnected);
});

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
}); 


printer.alignCenter();
printer.println("Hello world");
printer.cut();
printer.execute(function(err){
    if (err) {
        console.error("Print failed", err);
    } else {
     console.log("Print done");
    }
});
```

#### Epson SDK (Code)

```js
var ePosDev = new epson.ePOSDevice();

function connect() {
  var ipAddress = '192.168.77.22';
  var port = '515';
  ePosDev.connect(ipAddress, port, callback_connect);
}

function callback_connect(resultConnect){
    alert('Callback Called');
    var deviceId = 'local_printer';
    var options = {'crypto' : false, 'buffer' : false};
    alert(resultConnect);

    if ((resultConnect == 'OK') || (resultConnect == 'SSL_CONNECT_OK')) {
        alert('Connected!');
        ePosDev.createDevice(deviceID,ePosDev.DEVICE_TYPE_PRINTER,options,callback_createDevice);       
    }
    else {
        alert('Not Connected!');
    }
}

var printer = null;

function callback_createDevice(deviceObj, errorCode){
  if (deviceObj === null) {
//Displays an error message if the system fails to retrieve the Printer object
return; }
  printer = deviceObj;
//Registers the print complete event
  printer.onreceive = function(response){
    if (response.success) {
//Displays the successful print message
}
else {
//Displays error messages
} };
}

function createData(){
  printer.addTextAlign(printer.ALIGN_CENTER);
  printer.addText("Hello World\n");
}

function send(){
  if (ePosDev.isConnected) {
    printer.send();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When I widened my search, I discovered that the printer was listening for commands on another port!

```
nc -z 192.168.77.22 1-50000
```

...retuned the following results:

```
Connection to 192.168.77.22 port 80 [tcp/http] succeeded!
Connection to 192.168.77.22 port 515 [tcp/printer] succeeded!
Connection to 192.168.77.22 port 9100 [tcp/hp-pdl-datastr] succeeded!
```

So, I simply changed the port number to 9100 in the **init** portion of the code and voila!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the port in my Epson TM-M30 POS printer has changed from official '8008' to '515'.

The problem is that *epos-2.7.0.js* has declared the connection ports as a constant:

```
    ...
    this.IFPORT_EPOSDEVICE = 8008;
    this.IFPORT_EPOSDEVICE_S = 8043;
    ...
```

But the real one is 515, so you have to modify the official js:

```
    this.IFPORT_EPOSDEVICE = 515;
```

With this change, here is my code:

```
var ePosDev = new epson.ePOSDevice();
var ipAddress = '192.168.150.162'; 
var port = '515';
var printer = null;
ePosDev.connect(ipAddress, port, function callback_connect(resultConnect){
  var deviceId = 'local_printer';
  var options = {'crypto' : false, 'buffer' : false};
  if ((resultConnect == 'OK') || (resultConnect == 'SSL_CONNECT_OK')) {
    //Retrieves the Printer object
    ePosDev.createDevice(
      deviceId, 
      ePosDev.DEVICE_TYPE_PRINTER, 
      options, 
      function callback_createDevice(deviceObj, errorCode){
        if (deviceObj === null) {
          return; 
        }
        printer = deviceObj;
        printer.addTextAlign(printer.ALIGN_CENTER); 
        printer.addText('My text..\n');
        printer.send();
        if (ePosDev.isConnected) {
          printer.send(); 
        }
        ePosDev.deleteDevice(printer, function callback_deleteDevice(errorCode){
          ePosDev.disconnect();
        });
      });
  }});
```